# Redirect to another controller in yii2

Tags: arrays, redirect, yii2-advanced-app

I want to redirect to another action in different controller.
This is my ***code***:

```
$tempData[] = $rowData;
return $this->redirect(array('customize-header/show-headers', 'arr' => $tempData));
```

and this is the ***actionShowHeader*** in purpose controller:

```
public function actionShowHeaders($arr) {
    $model = new CustomizeHeader();
    $items = CustomizeHeader::getAllHeader();
    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
                'items' => $items,
    ]);
}
```

but I got this error

[image]

Anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error has been solved! I just convert the array using json_encode, this is the **code**: `$tempData = json_encode($arrayData); return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['customize-header/sorting-hea‌​ders', 'tempData' => $tempData]);`